# Zend Controller Action Helper Problem not able to add helper

Tags: zend-framework

Trying to make a controller helper to have similar functionality in some controllers using the preDispatch method.

Error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Helper_Action_Test' not found in /var/www/zend.dev/application/Bootstrap.php on line 9`
```

Application layout

```
/Application
 /Helpers
   **/Actions** this is where i will save the classes
   /Views
 /modules
 /configs
 /layouts
 /Bootstrap.php
```

In the Bootstrap I have added:

```
protected function _initActionHelpers(){
  Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper(new Helper_Action_Test());
}
```

In the helper file I have:

```
class Helper_Action_Test extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract{

    public function  preDispatch() {
       echo 'Test';
    }

}
```

When I do this in the bootstap it works, it might have to do with the include or how I am trying to instantiate the new class with the addHelper();

```
    include(APPLICATION_PATH.'/helpers/action/Test.php');
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper(new Test());
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
// Action Helpers
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath(
    APPLICATION_PATH .'/controllers/helpers');
$hooks = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('Quote');
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($hooks);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the helper file bootstrap file I think.

Or I think you want to: `require_once()` it

Answer (score 0):

By adding the following lines in your config file you will be able to achieve what you want

```
; Include path
includePaths.library                = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"

; Autoloader Namespace
autoloaderNamespaces[]              = 'Helper_'
```

More info in the official ZF doc [Autoloader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html#zend.loader.autoloader.usage)

Comment: Hi Jeff, Thanks for your reply. Does this require me to put the Helpers folder in the library folder?

Comment: This way, yes, you would have to put your helpers in the library folder. If you want to use the defaut way of storing your helpers you whould name you classes Zend_View_Helper_HelperName and extend Zend_View_Helper_Abstract and have a public method in it called HelperName() which could be called with $this->helperName() from the view

Comment: These are action helpers though and I have to extend Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract, to get all the action controller stuff..

Comment: You only need to store helpers in the library folder if these helpers are common to all applications. If it's specific to one application, the best place is inside your application folder.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, make sure the _initAutoload() on your bootstrap is the first method and also make sure you have added the prefix path:

```
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPrefix('Helper_Action');
```

You can aslo provide the path to the classes if they are not on the include_path:

```
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/helper/action/', 'Helper_Action');
```

Comment: Hi Kenye, tried this, still getting the error, class cannot be found. I've also moved the method underneath the _initAutoload method. When I try to instantiate Helper_Action_Test() from anywhere it still doesnt find it... Include path not working as I want it to I guess. Any other ideas?

Comment: Post your entire bootstrap and config so that we can reproduce your environment.

Comment: just noticed line 17 of that paste should be as below but it still doesnt work.. Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/helpers/action/', 'Helper_Action');